# How to check if the file contains certain values before reading in Talend Studio

Tags: talend

Hello beginner in Talend Studio here and first time poster. I am using Talend 8.0 and have a text file to ingest into a database that has the following:

H2||ID||portfolio||manager||name

D||5||8001-1101||48||John Doe

D||6||8001-1102||50||John Doe

D||7||8002-1101||20||Jane Doe

F3||||||||

where the delimiter is a double pipe (||)

ID, portfolio, manager and name and its associated records are the data I'd like to ingest. The first column with "H2", "D" and "F3" are the header, detail and footer indicators respectively. These indicators are not supposed to be ingested but will need to be checked for their presence when the file is read into talend studio.

I need to check if these three indicators are available in the file. If either of these indicators are not in the file, it should not ingest the file and output a message. If the indicators do exist, the data is ingested but only the data for the columns "ID","portfolio","manager" and "name"

I tried using the following components:
[image]

Which will read the table in its entirety including the H2 column. I then use t-map with a filter

```
row1.Header.contains("D")
```

[image]

which keeps rows that has "D" indicator. Appreciate if there is a better way to do this

Comment: row1.Header.contains("D")&&row1.Header.contains("H2")&&row1.Header.contains("F3")

Comment: if you are trying to get the reject add new output and check output reject "true"

Answer (score 0):

Use `row1.Header.contains("D")&&row1.Header.contains("H2")&&row1.Header.contains("F3")`  to filter header in ("D","H2","F3")

If you want the reject check the option in an other output and `check output reject to true`